# Recoger valor de un AlertDialog

Tags: android, alertdialog

Estoy creando un `Alertdialog` pero el valor que me devuelve siempre es 0.
He definido una variable en el Activity y le asigno el valor pero no me funciona. Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

```
private int result;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCustomTitle(myMsg)
            .setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result = which;
                    Log.d("DIALOG", result);
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    Log.d("METODO", ""+result);
```

El log dentro del dialogo "DIALOG" efectivamente me devuelve el valor correcto
pero la variable result en el log "METODO" siempre es igual a cero y no se como recoger el valor que me devuelve el dialog. He leido en la documentacion que no es posible aplicar un wait, como hace el JOptionPane en Java, lo que podría resover mi problema.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de la clase completa.

Comment: Solo puedes obtener el valor modificado cuando se da clic en el AlertDialog, ya que no ejecuta este  metodo automaticamente por lo tanto no puede cambiar el valor, agregue una explicacion @M.J.D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La explicaciòn es que cuando se realiza esta parte del còdigo, se crea el `AlertDialog`, pero no se modifica el valor de la variable `result` en ese momento, por lo tanto solo se imprime el mismo valor:

```
Log.d("METODO", ""+result);
```

La variable `result` unicamente cambiara al dar clic en el `AlertDialog`, ya que el metodo `onClick()` solo se llama al ejecutar esta acciòn.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result = which;
                    Log.d("DIALOG", result);
                }
```

Comment: Comprendo, ya he conseguido recoger el valor incluyendo el código dentro del dialog, pero el asunto se complica, ya que en realidad son varios dialogs los que tengo que mostrar, una vez acaba el primero salta el segundo, luego el tercero, como una bateria de preguntas.

Comment: El problema que veo que el código comienza a aparecer algo confuso de esta manera.